# Process handles instead of file handles for a process

Tags: c#, winapi, unmanaged

In the [Iain's Code](https://vmccontroller.svn.codeplex.com/svn/VmcController/VmcServices/DetectOpenFiles.cs) to find the handles for a process,it is configured to only get the "FILE" handles but i also need the "PROCESS" handles but not able to.Can some one point me in the right direction.
Thanks

Comment: The tags are in contradiction. [C#] cannot be used to write [unmanaged] code. Please clarify which one you want.

Comment: I hate comments that are not useful ^

Comment: I hate selfish people that believe their questions should be helpful only to themselves. This is not the philosophy of SO. Please fix your tags, and contribute to the searchability of this site.

Comment: My application is written in C# using unmanaged code.

Comment: Of course, anything running inside the CLR is effectively using unmanaged code. How is this related to the question, though? Likewise, the [winapi] tag is wrong. The code is using the [Native API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_API), not the Windows API.

Comment: There's just no point in using code like this to obtain process handles.  Hacking file handles is forbidden knowledge since it is always used to corrupt files randomly and undiagnosably.  Or maliciously, handle recycle attacks are an unsolved problem.  Nothing forbidden about processes, the .NET Process class gives you everything you need.  Like GetProcessById() and the Handle property.

Comment: @IInspectable Would you mind supporting your claim with a link? I wrote massive unmanaged chunks of code in C# (not related to the question).

Comment: @xxbbcc [Standard ECMA-334 - C# Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm) and the referenced [Standard ECMA-335 - Common Language Infrastructure (CLI)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm). With that out of the way, would you mind sharing your unmanaged C# code with the rest of the world?

Comment: @IInspectable Any time you call an API function or any time you use unmanaged pointers, you're dealing with unmanaged code. The fact that you initiate the call from the managed runtime makes no difference. You can use raw pointers, you can perform direct memory access, etc. in C#. (Not that one should but the possibility is open.)

Comment: @xxbbcc You are confusing *unsafe* with *unmanaged*. Accessing unsafe pointers through C# is still done through managed code (CIL). P/Invoke does not produce unmanaged code either. C# compiles to CIL. Always. Writing unmanaged code requires C++/CLI.

Answer (score 3):

Just modify the code to add more logic after the line

```
if (GetHandleType(handle, handleEntry.OwnerPid, out handleType) && handleType == SystemHandleType.OB_TYPE_FILE)
```

If you want to handle handles of type `process`, use something like:

```
bool result = GetHandleType(handle, handleEntry.OwnerPid, out handleType);
if (result)
{
    switch (handleType)
    {
        case SystemHandleType.OB_TYPE_FILE:
        {
            // Existing code:
            string devicePath;
            ....
        }           
        break;

        case SystemHandleType.OB_TYPE_PROCESS:
        {
            // Your code here
            ....
        }           
        break;
    }
}
```

---

> Thanks and also is there a way to find the process name from the
>   handle value if the the switch case is Process type ?

Sure you can. But you'll have to get a deep understanding of the Win32 API and how handles work. Basically, you want to *duplicate* the handle of the other process that owns the handle in your own process, using `DuplicateHandle` (so you gain access to it). Then you need to allocate unmanaged memory, call `NtQueryObject` with the good parameters so it'll fill your unmanaged memory with bytes that you'll then have to marshal back to a structure that contains information about your (process) handle.

Have a deep look at the code you linked, everything is written there. Especially the `GetFileNameFromHandle` functions.

1) Duplicate the handle in our own process

```
processHandle = NativeMethods.OpenProcess(ProcessAccessRights.PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, true, processId);
if (NativeMethods.DuplicateHandle(processHandle.DangerousGetHandle(), handle, currentProcess, out objectHandle, 0, false, DuplicateHandleOptions.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS))
{
    handle = objectHandle.DangerousGetHandle();
}
```

2) Allocates unmanaged memory... (you'll have to destroy it later)

```
ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(length);
```

3)... then pass it to `NtQueryObject` with the rights parameters

```
NT_STATUS ret = NativeMethods.NtQueryObject(handle, OBJECT_INFORMATION_CLASS.ObjectNameInformation, ptr, length, out length);
```

4) Marshal back to known struct. In the original code, it's a simple string.

```
fileName = Marshal.PtrToStringUni((IntPtr)((int)ptr + 8), (length - 9) / 2);
```

In your case, the right structure is `SYSTEM_HANDLE_ENTRY`. Google for this to have usage examples.

Comment: Thanks and also is there a way to find the process name from the handle value if the the switch case is Process type ?

Comment: @Robert I provided more details. see edit